# PHP imap_open failing, but OpenSSL connects

Tags: php, openssl, imap, ssl, pop3

Im trying to connect to a POP3 server via `imap_open`

```
imap_open('{mail.domain.com:995/pop3/tls}INBOX', 
    'user@domain.com', 
    'password');
```

But I get these errors:

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.domain.com:995/pop3/tls}INBOX
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
Notice: Unknown: POP3 connection broken in response (errflg=2)
```

(in that order, which is strange as the notice is after the fatal error)

Running this command in terminal works fine:

```
> openssl s_client -crlf -connect mail.domain.com:995

+OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
USER user@domain.com
+OK
PASS password
+OK User successfully logged on.
```

I have tried various other switches like `/novalidate-cert`, `/debug`, `OP_DEBUG` but get the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the server specified TLS, connecting with SSL in PHP worked.

```
imap_open('{mail.domain.com:995/pop3/ssl}INBOX', 
    'user@domain.com', 
    'password');
```

Comment: if I'm using imtp instead of pop3 how to use imap_open??